# How to link Cocoa Touch Static Library and Application Xcode 5 projects in the same workspace?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've done the following steps:

1. Create an Xcode workspace
2. Right click the project navigator, choose new project, and add a Cocoa Static Touch Framework to the workspace
3. Right click the project navigator, choose new project, and add a Single View Application to the workspace
4. In the Single View Application's target, under Linked Frameworks and Libraries, add the libFrameworkName.a
5. In the Single View Application's Build Settings, add -ObjC to the Other Linker Flags

Now I'd like to go into the App Delegate of the Single View Application and `#import "MyFramework"` but it is not found.

What am I missing to Link the new Framework with the sample application?

I've obviously tried cleaning and building the project but that is not working.  I think there must be some way to indicate that the Framework is a dependency of the Application but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I had similar problem. When I included my static lib, Xcode wouldn't autocomplete the header file names but it did autocomplete the classes/methods from that library. I assumed its Xcode bug. But, I was able to successfully compile the program though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build settings of the Sample Application search for "Search Paths".  Add "../" as a recursive search path for User Header Search Paths.